# TypeMismatchError on post

Tags: aurelia, microsoft-edge, aurelia-fetch-client

I'm writing an `aurelia` application with `aurelia-fetch-client` library.
When I try to post an object to my api service I get the error:

> TypeMismatchError

In console only from Edge. Other browsers (Chrome, Firefox and IE11) have no problems. There are no description or any other details about it.

Comment: @jrbedard Have you tried to breakpoint the API to see if it's the api that is causing the error or the client?

Comment: @James I tried to breakpoint the api, but the error happen before its execution, so I assumed it's a client problem

Answer (score 1):

In all but the newest versions of Edge you need to include the **fetch** polyfill in order for `aurelia-fetch-client` to work. I think it's supported since version 14 but I wouldn't necessarily rely on it. Edge is known to be quirky with some of these things (the Promise implementation is also horribly slow, which is why I personally always use bluebird)

You can install it with `npm i whatwg-fetch --save` and make sure to import it + include it in your bundle config (the instructions for this depend on which build system you're using)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and sorry for not being precise, but I'm already using whatwg-fetch and I have the same problem with it and without it